# Export certificate from IIS using PowerShell

Tags: iis, powershell

How do I export a self-signed certificate from [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) 7 using PowerShell?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
dir cert:\localmachine\my | Where-Object { $_.hasPrivateKey } |   Foreach-Object { [system.IO.file]::WriteAllBytes("c:\$($_.Subject).pfx",     ($_.Export('PFX', 'secret')) ) }
```

Source: *[Exporting Certificate With Private Key](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/10/20/exporting-certificate-with-private-key.aspx)*

This will export all of your certificates into `C:\`.

You can check what certificates you have by running:

```
dir cert:\localmachine\my
```

Comment: Thanks, the code above works well, however I'm need to export the certifcates as .cer rather than pfx - any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Found the following will work - thanks for your help


dir cert:\localmachine\my | Where-Object { $_.hasPrivateKey } |   Foreach-Object { [system.IO.file]::WriteAllBytes("c:\shared\test\$($_.Subject).cer",     ($_.Export('CERT', 'secret')) ) }

Answer (score 7):

Worth noting that when I tried to export my root certificates, I had to use Thumbprint as the filename, not Subject, due to invalid foreign-language characters in the unicode. This works:

```
dir cert:\localmachine\root |
Foreach-Object { [system.IO.file]::WriteAllBytes("c:\temp\$($_.Thumbprint).cer",     ($_.Export('CERT', 'secret')) ) }
```

Comment: I was getting the  "Illegal characters in path." error when trying to use $_.Subject, but the $_.Thumbprint works. Thanks!

Comment: How do you export only non-expired certificates?