# From certificate Alias to PEM File with private key included using Java

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, keystore, pem

**I have  this code to generate a CER file using the alias:**

```
public class TestFromAliasToCER {

    public static final int KEY_SIZE = 1024;
    public static final String BEGIN_CERT = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----";
    public static final String END_CERT = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
    public final static String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException {


           KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance ("Windows-MY");
           keyStore.load (null, null);         
           Enumeration<String> aux = keyStore.aliases();
           String alias = aux.nextElement();
           X509Certificate  certificate = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate (alias);
           String certString = formatCrtFileContents(certificate);         
           PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("cert.CER");
           out.println(certString);
           out.close();

    }

    public static String formatCrtFileContents(final Certificate certificate) throws CertificateEncodingException { 

        final Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getMimeEncoder(64, LINE_SEPARATOR.getBytes());
        final byte[] rawCrtText = certificate.getEncoded();
        final String encodedCertText = new String(encoder.encode(rawCrtText));
        final String prettified_cert = BEGIN_CERT + LINE_SEPARATOR + encodedCertText + LINE_SEPARATOR + END_CERT;
        return prettified_cert;
    }
}
```

**This creates the cer file with**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
data
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I want to be able to create a PEM Certificate with the private key included, is it possible? If not, why?

I'm not restricted to Java only and free to use any Java API, but preferable with the least user interaction as possible.

Comment: Does it have to be a PEM file? Often when you want to have a certificate and the private key in one container, you use pkcs#12.

Comment: At the moment I'm using **openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -out cert.pem**, but this needs to have the .pfx file.  I need to send an XML file to a web service and I do this using **curl**

Comment: You could create a PKCS#12 file as quinz suggested, and then serialize it and construct it to any format you would like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I don't see it documented, according to the source the SunMSCAPI provider implements only a stub for `getEncoded` and **cannot export Windows privatekey** so you can't do this with JCA.

You could of course write JNI or JNA to call Windows CAPI, but that's not simple.

To use existing tools without user interaction you can use `Runtime` or `ProcessBuilder` to

- run `certutil` with arguments `-exportpfx -user -p password certid filename`
- run `powershell` and tell it to select an object in `cert:\currentuser\my` and invoke the `Export('PFX','password')` method -- [examples for machine rather than user cert here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563636/export-certificate-from-iis-using-powershell)
- or in (only) recent powershell use `Export-PFXCertificate` cmdlet [documentation here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848635%28v=wps.630%29.aspx)

and after any of these, extract from pkcs12 to PEM with `openssl pkcs12`, or if you prefer with Java by:

- load the PKCS12 keystore and get the PrivateKey entry
- call `getEncoded` and encode the result in folded (MIME) base64 like you did for the certificate except use `-----BEGIN/END PRIVATE KEY-----`

Warning: Java produces an unencrypted (PKCS8) privatekey, so make certain no unauthorized user or program ever has access to this file, your disk/filesystem or any backup(s).

Comment: Thank you, this method works only if the user when he installed the certificate checked the option "mark the private key as exportable." according to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/232154/iis-export-private-key-option-is-grayed-when-exporting-a-server-certificate

Comment: @afgh: if the key is unexportable, you can't ever get it out to any kind of file by any means, so your question is moot

Answer (score 2):

A digital certificate doesn't have the private key **inside** it (the private key is not part of the certificate fields). The certificate and the private key are **separate** entities, although they're **related** (one can't exist without the other).

If you take a look at the certificate fields in [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1), you'll see that only the **public key** is part of it:

```
Certificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    tbsCertificate       TBSCertificate,
    signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
    signatureValue       BIT STRING  }

TBSCertificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
      ... lots of fields
    subjectPublicKeyInfo SubjectPublicKeyInfo,
      ... lots of other fields
    }
```

The `subjectPublicKeyInfo` is the public key, and there's no field for the private key.

That's because certificates are meant to be public (you can have more details on why they're public taking a look at how a [Public Key Infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) works).

Although the certificate is public, there's always a correspondent private key somewhere, usually held by the certificate's owner (and ideally by no one else).

---

Anyway, the file you've got (with **BEGIN CERTIFICATE** and **END CERTIFICATE** headers) in only the digital certificate (but not the private key).

If you have the private key and the corresponding certificate, you can create a file that contains both. The most common formats for such file are: **JKS** (also known as Keystore) and **PFX**.

There are also another "format": the Windows repository (the one you're reading when you do `KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY")`). I don't know exactly in what format its files are, but the `KeyStore` class abstracts it.

If the private key is present, it will be together with its corresponding certificate, in the same alias. You can check if the key is present with this code:

```
String alias = aux.nextElement();
if (keyStore.isKeyEntry(alias)) { // alias contains a private key
    Key key = keyStore.getKey(alias, "password".toCharArray()); // need to know the password
    // key is the private key

    // cert is the key's corresponding certificate
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
} else if (keyStore.isCertificateEntry(alias)) { // alias doesn't contain a key
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
}
```

After having the key, you can save it to another keystore with the following code:

```
// create another keystore
KeyStore output = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

// "alias" - choose to whatever name you want
// privateKey is the object you've got from keyStore.getKey()
// "password" is the password for this alias
// cert will be stored in the same alias
output.setKeyEntry("alias", privateKey, "password".toCharArray(), new Certificate[] { cert });

// save the keystore to a file
output.store(new FileOutputStream("outputfile.jks"), "keystore password".toCharArray());
```

The code above creates the file `outputfile.jks` containing the certificate and the private key.

If you want the file to be a **PFX**, you can change the code above to:

```
// PKCS12 == PFX format
KeyStore output = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

// alternative: in pfx, I think that alias can't have specific passwords
// so you can use this as it doesn't require a password for the alias entry
output.setKeyEntry("alias", privateKey.getEncoded(), new Certificate[] { cert });

// change file extension to ".pfx"
output.store(new FileOutputStream("outputfile.pfx"), "keystore password".toCharArray());
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer, this is actually what I want, but when trying to save it to pfx the instruction **output.setKeyEntry("alias", privateKey.getEncoded(), new Certificate[] { cert });**  I get the next exception **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: encoding must not be null** because privateKey.getEncoded() is null. When trying to do the "JKS" method is another exception about not being PKCS8 encoded, this problem led me to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332280/convert-private-key-to-pkcs8-format-in-java

Comment: Did you check the contents of the privateKey and the certificate? Maybe you can't have access to the private key - as explained in [Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44319987/7605325)

Comment: If the certificate is in a Windows repository, you can also export it manually: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754329(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: This is actually my current solution, let the user export it manually, is not fancy but gets the job done.