# How to read Private Key form Windows Key Store?

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature, keystore, pki

Is it possible to read valid private key from windows keystore like Windows-MY, Windows-ROOT in java? I can read private key from other storages eg: pkcs12 (.pfx, .p12), pkcs11, jks(.jks), jceks . I have tried something like this but which works fine for the other keystores but Windows-MY and Windows-ROOT return invalid and not-null Private key.

NB: here, private key and public key in chains is a valid key-pair.

```
final char[] keyPass = "test1234".toCharArray();
X509Certificate[] chains=......;

KeyStore sourceKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
sourceKeyStore.load("null", keyPass);

Enumeration<String> sAliases = sourceKeyStore.aliases();
while (sAliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    String alias = sAliases.nextElement();
    Key privKey = sourceKeyStore.getKey("testName", keyPass); // privKey is not null here but misses some information

    sourceKeyStore.setKeyEntry("testName", privKey, keyPass, chains); //gives Key protection algorithm not found error
}
```

Comment: No, it is not possible through the Java apis.

Comment: Dupe A but not exactly Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44311086/from-certificate-alias-to-pem-file-with-private-key-included-using-java

Comment: @JamesKPolk thanks. It would be better if you add this as an answer then it would be more visible for the new comer.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I have cheked that question though it is related mine still provides lots of information in this topic